# What is happening to my SU rep? (Or, how is my rep changing before my eyes!)

Tags: support

So today I've had a fair few upvotes, no downvotes - reached 6660 on SU, then went and had some tea. Came back, 6668. Damn, a downvote! Who has offended my honour so?

Nobody, apparently. Now my rep is on 6666, and both my rep chart and recent activity page show no reason for this. I don't mind the rep change, but I'd love to know what's going on? Is this the fabled rep-recalc, and if so, why is it taking so much time? Are there sinister forces at work?

For illustrative purposes, here's an image showing both my current rep, my no-downvotes recent user page, AND how much rep I've gained today (my, aren't you lucky)

[My reputation, it's no longer a round number http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2502059/SUR.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2502059/SUR.png)

Answer (score 7):

According to my [rep tracker](http://csharpindepth.com/StackOverflow/ReputationTracker.aspx?so=&sf=&su=6998&meta=&mode=today&showflair=true) it's from the ["`/var/run` on debian"](https://superuser.com/questions/90114/90116#90116) answer - that's received 5 upvotes and 2 downvotes; it shows as +46 on my tracker.

I'm not sure why you're not seeing those downvotes yourself though...

Comment: ...huh, viewing the up/downvotes on the question, I did indeed get two downvotes. So why aren't they listed on the recent activity page, OR my rep graph? Thanks for clearing it up, anyway :)

Comment: They probably show on the second page - the front page only shows the top five items, and downvotes are seldom in the top five...

Comment: There they are. Well, I feel a fool - I thought the recent page was, y'know, recent, not in score-order?

Comment: @phoshi: yeah, took me a while to figure that out too.  :)

Answer (score 3):

if you narrow the time slice on the reputation graph, you can see the affected answers on the right side

[image]

narrowing is not really needed, but helps... sometimes looking in the future - advancing end date by 1 or 2 days - is also needed...

Comment: Yeah, that totally wasn't there last time I looked, honest!

Answer (score 2):

Your screenshot shows the "summary" tab of your user history; what does the "reputation" tab show? The former only shows the top 5 scoring "recent" events; the latter shows all of them (especially when you explicitly click "today" to be sure the time frame is correct). If you have had a number of upvotes recently, you need to select "reputation" to see your downvotes.